# Effect of total database size in overall performance

Tags: database, performance, size

When i create database and build up the content (total size about 3 Gbs), the process is very fast and i the CPU usage is stable at  about 80%. After finishing, i build another similar database, the process is much slower and the CPU usage is stable at only about 20-30%, even though the first database was not being used.

1. Would anyone point out some factors and why i can't increase the CPU usage to make the process faster?
2. In a shared host, they says my database is big. They say even though the database is not being used (i disconnected it from my site to test how it affect the performance), it still affect the overall performance because of "MySQL usage". From what i know, the only 2 factors affecting server performance is CPU and RAM usage. So what is "MySQL usage" here?

Thank you in advance!